# How to ignore folder from compilation errors?

Tags: reactjs, craco

all!

I'm trying to add a 3rd party library  called globekit to my create-react-app setup and I'm getting a few errors related to the compilation of this package, as it is natively meant to be used to vanilla js.

Here's how I'm importing it:

```
import { GlobeKitView, PointGlobe, Atmosphere, Background } from '../../../globe/globekit.esm.js';
```

Here are the errors I'm getting:

[image]

Is there any way to avoid those errors, by ignoring the library folder somehow? This works just fine under vanilla JS. Any other suggestions?

Thank you very much!

Comment: just put `eslint-ignore` flag in this file

Comment: Thank you, it solved my problem! :)